# Hover not working on <li>!

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make the text on my navigation bar to show an underline on mouse-over but for some reason it doesn't work. I've used the CSS from the Hover-master collection and just a simple navigation list. What to do?!

Have I used the Hover-master collection wrong?

EDIT: I just inserted my whole code and in the snippet it works but when I run the html file in the browers it doesn't...

EDIT2: The files are hosted @ http://fransbergstrom.kaggteknik.se/ and as you can see, the links doesn't work, and the code is an exact copy of the ones pasted below.

HTML & CSS:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
@font-face {
  font-family: Fairview;
  src: url("fonts/Fairview_Regular.otf");
}
/*PRE-CLASSES:*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
  html {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);
    zoom: 0.75;
    zoom: 75%;
  }
  /*Zooma ut vid mac så websidan anpassar sig*/
}
div {
  display: block;
}
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
body {
  background-color: gray;
  font-family: 'Fairview';
  color: #444444;
}
/*   ID's: */

/* NAVIGATION MENU */

#navlist {
  margin-top: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#navlist li {
  display: inline
}
#navlist li a {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}
/*FRONT PAGE*/

#container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu-nav {
  height: 130px;
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}
#menu-logo {
  height: 130px;
  width: 20%;
  background: url("images/menulogo.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  float: left;
}
/* NEWS */

#news {
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 140px;
  height: 340px;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}
#news-opacity {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 340px;
  width: 49%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
}
#news-right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}
#news-right p {
  margin-top: 90px;
  color: #e04e21;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#news-right b {
  margin-top: 90px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 93px;
}
#news-middle {
  margin-top: 60px;
  height: 70%;
  width: 4%;
  background: url("images/news-divider.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  float: left;
}
#news-left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}
#news-left p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}
#news-left h1 {
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: #e04e21;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}
/* HEADER */

#header {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
#header-opacity {
  position: absolute;
  height: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: -1;
}
/* CLASSES: */

.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat 0px;
}
/* Underline From Center */

.hvr-underline-from-center {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hvr-underline-from-center:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2098d1;
  height: 4px;
  -webkit-transition-property: left, right;
  transition-property: left, right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-underline-from-center:hover:before,
.hvr-underline-from-center:focus:before,
.hvr-underline-from-center:active:before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCUTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="standard.css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="background">
    <div id="header-opacity"></div>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="menu">
        <div id="menu-logo"></div>
        <div id="menu-nav">
          <ul id="navlist">
            <li><a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-center">Start</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-center"><font color="#e04e21">Kontakt</font></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-center">Info</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-center"><font color="#e04e21">Turneringar</font></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-center">Biljetter</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="news">
        <div id="news-opacity"></div>
        <div id="news-right">
          <p>WELCOME</p>
          <b>TO MONSTERHACK</b>
        </div>
        <div id="news-middle">
        </div>
        <div id="news-left">
          <h1>Har kommer det sta nagot</h1>
          <b></b>
          <p>Som informerar lasaren</p>
          <b></b>
          <p>Om eventet med mera</p>
          <b></b>
          <p>Samt dirigerar den till biljetter</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't have any hover styles except for the `:before` elment which seems to center it?

Comment: I just copy paste your code into the snippet editing your question and seems to work fine....

Comment: Is it possible that there are additional styles that you did not include that are causing your problem? Running your code snippet actually works.

Comment: Just updated my post with the full HTML and CSS, ran the snippet and it worked, however no on-hover effect (not even the <a> tag link) works when I open the html in the browser...

Comment: It seems like the a tag doesn't even work because I dont get directed anywhere when I click on the text ... I uploaded the files to my server and the problem still exists.. see http://fransbergstrom.kaggteknik.se/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `z-index:-1;` from .background{}. You dropped the whole page below "sea level", so hover event do not fires. ;)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding the font-size attribute to .hvr-underline-from-center:hover ?

add this to the css:

.hvr-underline-from-center:hover {
`font-size: 30px;`
}

Answer (score 0):

```
   #navlist li a:hover {
    font-size: 55px;
   }
```

Add that line to your CSS and put your own pixels value instead of '55px' to play around the text size when hovering

http://jsbin.com/hesisohuse/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Okey I just figured it out, for some reason my `.background` class caused the problem. By removing        `position=absolute;`       from the class my  tags became clickable again.

I don't know why this happends but at least it fixed my problem.